# A Char variable in C changing value

Tags: c, char

[Here is what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGMzJ.jpg)

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char v1=0;
    char v2=0;
    printf("Enter the number of elements of first vectors : ");
    scanf(" %d",&v1);
    printf("v1=%d\n",v1);
    printf("Enter the number of elements of second vectors : ");
    scanf(" %d",&v2);
    printf("v2=%d\n",v2);
    printf("v1=%d\n",v1);
    printf("v2=%d\n",v2);
    return 0;
}
```

If we assumed v1=50 and v2=300
Why does v1 value changes in the second print

Comment: If your compiler isn't yelling at you, turn up the warning levels.

Comment: the variable you read with `%d` must be `int`, not `char`.

Comment: You can print it with `%d` because of default argument promotions, but that doesn't work with pointers.

Comment: `v2=300` How are you going to fit 300 into a 1-byte char?

Comment: Re “A Char variable in C changing value”: Changing values is what variables do. It is their primary purpose to vary. You should write a more descriptive and specific title.

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/12149471)

Answer (score 1):

here is what my compiler says with warning turned up max

> > warning C4477: 'scanf' : format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'char *'

you need

```
scanf(" %c",&v1);
```

Comment: It works find in my compiler , I get the first printf output normally but the second for v1 comes out as 1

Comment: @Optix OK well you have a poor compiler, you might need to ramp up the warning level. I also provided the fix for you, did you try that

Comment: @Optix google "c undefined bahaviour"